# While getting diferential for x³ at x = 0 there isn't tangent line

Tags: derivatives

If we draw the grafic of the x³ we would see at x=0 it's 0 and its deritive is also 0. But deritive means that we should be able to draw a tangent line. But we can't at x=0. We can only draw a secant line. How is that

Comment: It definitely has a tangent line there.  The tangent line is horizontal.

Comment: What is your definition of "tangent line"?  What is your definition of "secant line"?

Comment: What you call a "secant line" *is* what others would still call a "tangent line", i.e. the straight line that is the best linear approximation of the function at that point.

Comment: OP may be confused with the fact that there isn't a local minimum or maximum, so it *looks* a bit like a secant line (at least, more so than the tangent to local extrema)

Comment: @Gauss You may be correct, but I think that it is generally best to let the asker provide details and clarification, rather than to put words in their mouth.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I totally agree - which is why I only suggested a hypothesis. Sometimes, I myself feel so confused with something that I don't really know how to explain why. That is when a gentle bit of "probing" comes in handy ;)

Comment: @Gauss doesn't a tangent line means i should thouch it then continue my way. But at this instance im going over the grafic. Am i approaching it wrongly?